# Nodejs genetic algorithm memory management?

Tags: javascript, node.js, brain.js

I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm and have the problem of heap memory getting too large. To the extend that it throws an error.
I'm afraid it has something to do with my population array. I displayed the memory usage while running the program and recognized it is growing and growing and never gets freed up.

Consider the following setup:

```
let used = {}

class Trainer {
    static breed = function(elite) {
        //code for making a new generation
        return brood
    }
    constructor() {
        this.population = []
    }
    async evolve(data, options, callback) {
        // potential point where the error may be
        // because I see the memory growing and never getting smaller
        // but I think it should get smaller because I don't
        // reference the old generation any more or do I ?
        while (error >= threshold) {
            // train each member of the population async
            // and than make a new population out of the elite
            const elite = this.population.slice(0, 10)
            this.population = Trainer.breed(elite) <--- ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            callback(info)
            used = process.memoryUsage()
        }
    }
}

const trainer = new Trainer
const data = getData()
const options = makeOptions()

function log(info) {
    console.log(info)
    console.log(used)
}

async function test() {
    await trainer.evolve(data, options, log)
}

test()
```

Now I have some questions.

Is it true that on each generation the old array is not referenced anymore and get's garbage collected and makes some free space in memory?

How can I analyze the memory usage by each function to get better inside of where the problem may is in my code?

Because the code is very large I tried to simplified my problem. But if you are interested in the complete code please have a look in my repo:
https://github.com/kiro7shiro/image-generator
You can find the described setup from above in the "/cli/image-generator-evolve.js" file.

Comment: Took a peek at your repo, but there's a lot going on there...  If I'm in your shoes,  to assist in identifying the memory leak, I'd follow the recipe at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-problems/, particularly towards the bottom of the article which addresses the Allocation Timeline tool to address JS and function usage of memory...

Comment: Thank you. But I'm getting a "403 Forbidden Error" if I try to reach the link you've posted. - Yes you are right it's a lot of code. Mainly to show a cli debug tool I build around the trainer class. So it's easier to test for me. If you download the code, npm install it and then goto the bin folder. You can get a help by typing "node image-generator evolve --help'. If you want to test the program on yourself. Make a new folder named "results" in the training folder and than type the above command without the --help flag.

Comment: Just tried the link in my prior comment, and it worked fine for me.  Even tried it via an "icognito" browser session.  If you still can't reach the link, just try searching on "chrome allocation timeline", as there are plenty of resources providing guidance on tracking down javascript memory leaks via chrome...

Comment: Yes, I did this, too. Thank you very much for your suggestion. It was helpful already. I figured out that my population was too large. In terms of memory. I was creating a new network for each genome and stored them all as an object. That was too much. Now I store only the json of each network and creating only one working class for all these genes. That helped a lot. I still see the memory growing. But not as much as before. I will continue searching for the leak.